# jQuery inArray Example within Filters

Tags: jquery, filter

Is such of functionality possible ?

```
function show_upload_fieldset_if_necessary () {

    var in_this_cases = new Array (2110,2120,2130,2140,2150,2160);
    $('.my_radiobuttons :input[value="$.inArray(in_this_cases)"]').click(function(event) {
        $('#id_my_upload_fieldset').slideDown('slow');
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't put Javascript or jQuery in a selector like that.

You could use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead:

```
$(".my_radiobuttons :radio").filter(function() {
  return $.inArray($(this).val(), in_this_cases) > -1;
}).click(function() {
  $('#id_my_upload_fieldset').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Comment: ..but I always get -1 ?

Comment: You have two options then. Change your Array to use strings `new Array("2110", "2120"...etc)` or else use `parseInt` inside `inArray`: `$.inArray(parseInt(this.value), in_this_cases) > -1;`

Comment: yep, with ("2110",.. i get 0 instead of -1

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using a selector like that, but you can use a filter like below to do it

```
function show_upload_fieldset_if_necessary () {

    var in_this_cases = new Array (2110,2120,2130,2140,2150,2160);
    $('.my_radiobuttons :input').filter(function(){
        return $.inArray(this.value, in_this_cases) != -1;
    }).click(function(event) {
        $('#id_my_upload_fieldset').slideDown('slow');
    });
}
```

Comment: `return ~$.inArray(this.value, in_this_cases)` ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff yes forgot about -1

Comment: `This one works:

    var in_this_cases = new Array    ('2110','2120','2130','2140','2150','2160');
$('.my_radiobuttons').click(function(event) {
    if ($.inArray (this.value, in_this_cases) > -1) {
        $('#id_my_upload_fieldset').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $('#id_my_upload_fieldset').hide();
    };
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
var $filtered = $('.my_radiobuttons :input').filter(function(){
     return $.inArray(this.value, in_this_cases) > -1
});
```